# pagination and images in ePub books

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ipad, epub

I build a epub engine that can read `ePub books` with many features like pagination, add note, highlight, search, etc. Everything is working fine but am stuck with 2 problems.

- First One: The pagination function as you know is a JavaScript function that will divide the contents of html file into pages based on the frame of web-view that load it and because the html may contains text and images the images also may be paginate so its will divid into 2 pages which does not make scenes i want the whole image to be appear especially the cover page.
- Second One: I usually got a empty page at the end of the chapter (html File) .. Do you know how can I prevent that?

> These are the `JavaScript` functions I use to paginate:

```
function setupBookColumns(){
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style;
    body.marginLeft = 0;
    body.marginRight = 0;
    body.marginTop = 0;
    body.marginBottom = 0;


    var bc = document.getElementById('book-columns').style;

    bc.width = (window.innerWidth * 2) + 'px !important';
    bc.height = (window.innerHeight-kMaxFont) + 'px !important';
    bc.marginTop = '0px !important';
    bc.webkitColumnWidth = window.innerWidth  + 'px !important';
    bc.webkitColumnGap = '0px';
    bc.overflow = 'visible';

    if ( gCurrentPage < 0 )
        gCurrentPage = 1;
    gProgress = gPosition = 0;

    var bi = document.getElementById('book-inner').style;
    bi.marginLeft = '0px';
    bi.marginRight = '0px';
    bi.padding = '0';

    gPageCount = document.body.scrollWidth / window.innerWidth;

    // Adjust the page count to 1 if it's invalid
    if (gPageCount < 1) {
        gPageCount = 1;
    }
}


function paginate()
    {   

    if (gClientHeight == undefined) {
        gClientHeight = document.getElementById('book-columns').clientHeight;
    }

    var leftBlocker = document.getElementById('left-blocker');
    var parent = leftBlocker.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(leftBlocker);
    leftBlocker.style.left = '-200px';

    var rightBlocker = document.getElementById('right-blocker');
    parent.removeChild(rightBlocker);
    rightBlocker.style.left = '-200px';

    setupBookColumns();

    parent.appendChild(leftBlocker);
    parent.appendChild(rightBlocker);
}
```

I load the html file (Chapter file) in a `webView` when its finish loading I call the paginate function which I posted above .. this give a number of pages based on the amount of text, size of text, the frame of what hold text (in my case the webView) .. so that I can goForward and goBack using a JavaScript function.

Comment: You should probably show us some code...

Comment: tell me what part of code you wanna me to show ?

Comment: Well, the parts you are having problems with? Preferably together with some example content.

Comment: ok @JulianD. when webviewDidFinishLoad delegate function fired i call tha paginate function that i posted above .

Comment: Sorry, that code doesn't tell me too much: how are you breaking pages? How are you displaying the pages? Try to refine your question to something more easy to grasp - we like to help, but not all of us have the time to work through all of your code to understand what the actual problem is...

Comment: @JulianD. i really don't know how can i describe my question simplest than this .. im just looking for a way to deal with images in the webView and why the pagination makes an extra page at the end of every chapter ? Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Malek_Jundi hi I am facing the same problem I have a book.html and i want to load it on uiwebview with pagination? how can I do this plzz help?